# highcharts destroy selected group annotation with button

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Hi i am not sure how to target or call the destroy feature in the annotations js file. But i can see it there.

I have tried a few things basically I have a simplified column chart (js fiddle link below). I have includeed the annotations plug-in, You'll need to draw a rectangle (lines don't work so well). If it is not selected (click to select it)  <<< that is my qualifier for destroy (it has to be selected) and onclick() button... I have provided the button and some attempt to target (this) group and call destroy. This is exhaustion attempt number 122 so I scraped out everything and I am just showing what I want to do.

[image]

Here is an example group (formmatted): annotation that I am trying to target and destroy from my chart.

```
<g class="highcharts-annotations-group-0" zIndex="7" clip-path="url(#highcharts-2)">
    <g class="highcharts-annotation" transform="translate(74,35)">
        <path fill="rgba(255,0,0,0.4)" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" d="M 0 0 L 324 213"></path>
        <rect x="-5" y="-5" width="334" height="223" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="transparent" stroke-dasharray="3,1" shape-rendering="crispEdges"></rect>
    </g>
    <g class="highcharts-annotation" transform="translate(76,34)">
        <path fill="rgba(255,0,0,0.4)" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" d="M 0 0 L 0 0"></path>
    </g>
    <g class="highcharts-annotation" transform="translate(81,38)">
        <path fill="rgba(255,0,0,0.4)" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" d="M 0 0 L 0 0"></path>
    </g>
</g>
```

[Here is the jsFiddle....and thank you in advance for your help!](https://jsfiddle.net/franktudor/Ly4d8mnm/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate on annotations (kept in allItems) and then check if `selectionMarker` exists. If yes, then call destroy() action.

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts(),
        each = Highcharts.each;

    each(chart.annotations.allItems, function(item, i) {
        if(item.selectionMarker) {
            item.destroy();
        }
    });
});
```

Example:

- https://jsfiddle.net/Ly4d8mnm/3/

Comment: Iteration in allitems. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

also if you want to keep deleting you need to first deselect the item you are going to destroy.

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts(),
        each = Highcharts.each;

    each(chart.annotations.allItems, function(item, i) {
        if(item.selectionMarker) {
            item.deselect();
            item.destroy();
        }
    });
});
```

live example: https://jsfiddle.net/Ly4d8mnm/4/

Comment: You can include the snippet in your answer: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/